# Aggregation distinct values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the distinct values and their amount in ElasticSearch.

This can be done via:

```
"distinct_publisher": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "publisher", "size": 0
        }
    }
```

The problem I've is that it counts the terms, but if there are values in publishers separated via a space e.g.:
"Chicken Dog"
and 5 documents have this value in the publisher field, then I get 5 for Chicken and 5 for Dog:

```
"buckets" : [
            {
                "key" : "chicken",
                "doc_count" : 5
            },
            {
                "key" : "dog",
                "doc_count" : 5
            },
            ...
        ]
```

But I want to get as the result:

```
"buckets" : [
            {
                "key" : "Chicken Dog",
                "doc_count" : 5
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting 5 buckets for each of `chicken` and `dog` is because your documents were [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) at the time that you indexed them.

This means elasticsearch did some small processing to turn `Chicken Dog` into `chicken` and `dog` (lowercase, and tokenize on space). You can see how elasticsearch will analyze a given piece of text into searchable tokens by using the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html), for example:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?&text=Chicken+Dog'
```

In order to aggregate over the "raw" distinct values, you need to utilize the `not_analyzed` mapping so elasticsearch doesn't do its usual processing. [This reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#updating-a-mapping) may help. You may need to reindex your data to apply the not_analyzed mapping to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was absolutely what I was looking for and also a detailed and very good answer.